# Oracle uses a lot of memory

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

> OS: Windows Server 2012
>
> DB: Oracle11g-r2

When you restart or turn on the server, everything works perfectly, the memory is normal, the number of sessions, too. But after 2-3 days of continuous work, the consumed memory increases, and the number of sessions increases significantly to 450+. As far as I know, the database session should be thrown out by itself and there should be no problems with it. But what happens to memory? At the moment, it is 5.4GB passed 3 days. Tomorrow will be even more.
In the end, the database will stop accepting new traffic connections, even if everything is unloaded.
Only restart helps. Help me pls
[image]

Comment: How much memory do you think it should use? How is the database configured? No, the database does not terminate idle sessions by default.

Comment: How many people connect to this "server"?  Seems way too under-powered to be a server, it's more like a stand-alone PC.   Your user sessions consume anywhere above 10M per session, so make sure they are disconnecting once all their work is done.

Comment: @BalazsPapp when the system starts, the memory consumed is up to 1GB., over the weekend increased to 5.4 gb. I do not know how the database is configured. I did not install. About the sessions already read.

Comment: @sandman With a maximum load of up to 50 people. This is a Cisco server. Currently burned 1 RAM. There are sessions that are simply inactive

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the distribution of PGA / SGA memory?

Comment: "*and the number of sessions increases significantly to 450+*" - that is a clear sign of a bug in the application(s) that connect to the database. Apparently the connections are not closed properly.

Comment: You can query the profiles and resource limits to see if the DB is configured to throw out the sessions, but it looks like it does not. In that case it is best to look at the application(s) in question. BTW you also need to look at the max values for the memory settings, it’s normally that a dB uses as many memory as you configure it to use

Answer (score 1):

> But after 2-3 days of continuous work, the consumed memory increases ...

Databases don't generally consume memory by themselves.  Even Oracle.  :-)

They do so on behalf of client Applications.

> ... the number of sessions increases significantly to 450+.

Sounds like those client Applications are opening connections and not closing them.

Have those Application(s) *changed* recently?

> As far as I know, the database session should be thrown out by itself

[By default] The database has *no knowledge* of which sessions are eligible to be killed off and so will leave them connected for as long as they "want" to be.  Whilst it *is* possible to configure Oracle to kill off idle sessions after a period of time, this would only be a "Band-Aid"; you have a underlying [Application] problem that needs to be resolved.

> I do not know how the database is configured. I did not install.

Then ask yourself (*very* honestly): are you the Right Person to be dealing with this problem?  Do you have enough information to even *look* at it?

I get the impression (apologies if I'm *completely* wrong) that you are an "Accidental DBA".  If that's the case, then I would suggest you need help from a *real* one, preferably the one that installed this database in the first place.

If you can, go back and *ask them* for assistance.

If you can't, then escalate this issue to your Management.  Switching your database "off and on again" every other day is *not* a viable, long-term solution to your problem - and it's not just *your* problem, either; it's a problem for your *entire organisation* and not one that you can "solve" in isolation.  You need input from the developers of those client Applications.

Comment: Why do you think that I do not need it? What do you think if I didn’t need it, would I look for an answer? Yes, I unfortunately have no experience in database administration. But I have a desire to learn and I do everything for this.leadership issued a task. The rest of their little worries. Thank you for answer

Comment: If you think Oracle is malfunctioning, then just log a service request with Oracle support. They will help you figure out what happens. Other than that, you can look at what the enterprise manager shows in terms of memory growth and sessions. But everything you say points to either (1) an application issue (starting sessions that it never closes) or (2) the server you run the database on is massively under powered to run the workload this application produces.

Comment: OK. Thank you all for your help. I will sort this out. I'll start right away with software that does not close sessions